# How do a run a group() and sum() query and return more than just the sum & the column used for grouping in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 tables, categories(name, image_data) & expenses (name, amount, date) that are related by has_and_belongs_to_many ( expenses has many categories, and categories has many expenses). I want to write an active record query that will select all categories with their associated expenses and group them by categories id and also return other columns in the categories table (the name & image_data)

I have tried

**1.**

```
Category.includes(:expenses).group('categories.id').sum(:amount)
```

but what i get is

```
{4=>0.75e5, 6=>0.18e6, 5=>0.0}
```

This does not return the columns in the categories table

**2.**

```
k = Category.includes(:expenses).group('categories.id').select('categories.*, SUM(expenses.amount) AS total_amount').pluck('categories.id', 'categories.name', 'total_amount')
```

but i get the error that the column name 'total_amount' is not known.

**3.**
I have also tried to group the results based on all the columns of the categories table that I want returned but I think I am making the query slow by doing this.

```
Category.includes(:expenses).group('id', 'name', 'image_data').sum(:amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include any column returned in the grouping, so the third option you have should work. This is just how an aggregation works in SQL, when you're grouping and counting/summing, there's only one row per grouped columns, so there's no way to include other non-grouped columns.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
categories = Category.left_joins(:expenses).group(:id).select("categories.*, sum(expcenses.amount) as total")

categories.first.total # => it defines total as a virtual attribute on the model
categories.first.name # => the category fields are also available on the Category model as usual, because of explicitly selected categories.*
```

This will return categories without expenses (with 0 sum) included. If you want to exclude them, use `.join` instead of `.left_joins`.

Note, even in some cases `includes` can work, it's not necessary will work always as it can also just be a separate query instead of the join (inner or left) that's needed here.